# FrSky receiver snap-on connection problem

Tags: antenna, receiver, frsky, frsky-xm+

The snap connector thingy (picture included) on the xm+ receiver (although it is the same with nearly every other receiver) I have stupidly disfigured, as well as the antenna end. Is it possible to fix this or solder the wires on directly? Do you have to get a new receiver because of some tiny connector which has been slightly (ok, fine, quite a lot) bent?

P.S.: Yes, I know this was very stupid and I will not make this mistake again!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once you've got it repaired or replaced one thing I normally do with U.FL connectors is  put a little dab of hot glue over the top, otherwise it's pretty easy for them to pop out when you're moving things around and as you've found they're pretty easy to damage if inserted / removed too many times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of connector is called a [U.FL connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL).

Replacing the connectors will be super fiddly, but is possible if you are skilled with a soldering iron. The cable side is the more difficult bit but also cheaper, so you might try a new antenna and replace just the PCB connector.

You may be able to use something small, like a pin, to carefully nudge the connector back into shape - it may make it worse, but if it doesn't work anyway what's to lose?!

Finally, you could unsolder the connector from the board, cut the wire and solder it directly. The wire will be a [coaxial cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_cable), so you need to take care not to short the inner to the outer - especially when soldering as you may melt the insulator away. The inner goes to the centre pin on the connector; the outer part to ground (the circle of the U.FL connector is connected to ground so you can use this pad).

Before you trust the receiver again you should do some range tests. You can put the transmitter in the range testing mode and check what kind of range you get.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed comment, your time is really appreciated! I understand the inner should go to the pin, should the outer metal shielding go to the circle surrounding the pin or does it not make a difference?

Comment: @SolomonPittPUPIL10OGLST The answer has been edited to clarify where to connect the outer (thanks to @bingo-fuel)